# How to specify the Audience for OBO Flow

Tags: msal-react

I am using the on-behalf-of flow where the token acquired on the front-end is then forwarded to a middle-tier-application. That middle-tier-application can then use that token to acquire tokens to other APIs (like Microsoft's Graph API) or to access resources that are local to it.

Very close to having this working, but I'm getting the following error: `AADSTS500131: Assertion audience does not match the Client app presenting the assertion...`

How do you specify the audience when acquiring a token using msal-react?